# Drop-down menu that supports categories and subcategories in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a form that supports putting an entry into a category and then a subcategory.  I'm new to programming and ror and have no idea where to start.

I'm making a database where you can enter a product type with a drop-down menu.  For example: toy, make-up or glasses.  I then want there to be a drop down menu below that that changes where it gets it's values depending on the entry of the above drop down menu.

For example if "toy" is chosen, the drop-down menu below gets data from a table that has values for "age group."

For "make-up," it should draw it's values from a table that has one column that has the different types of make up.

For glasses I want it to draw data from a table that has one column for "prescription."

I hope I'm being clear with what my question is. Part of being new to programming is not knowing the exact terms for things.  If clarification is necessary please let me know.  Any ideas will help.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to use Javascript for that

Comment: Do you know any kind of keywords I can search to learn how to do this with Javascript?

Comment: The point is: you must generate select for each possible option and then show/hide them with js depending on selected values. I'm not sure if there is any plugin to ease it out

Comment: Ha, got it! http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/DependentSelect

Comment: Also take a look here: https://github.com/jrsinclair/jquery-dependent-questions/wiki